# How to change the default font of firebug?

Tags: fonts, firebug

In Firebug, the default font is not very comfortable for me, and I made the change in Firefox menubar->tools->options, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change only font size, use `about:config` page and change option `extensions.firebug.textSize` or use `Increase font size` and `Decrease font size` options in the firebug menu (menu and hotkeys doesn't work in FF4 and Win7 on my laptop).

If you want to change font-families of UI elements you can modify firebug css files located in the extensions directory (`c:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\nd21zknl.default\extensions\firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi\skin\classic\firebug.css` for me).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to modify the extension's files (and to do it again after each Firebug update...)

All you have to do is to add rules to the file `<FirefoxProfile>/chrome/userChrome.css` (create it if it doesn't exist yet):

```
#fbCommandArrow, .fbCommandLine, #fbCommandEditor {
    font-family: Consolas, monospace !important; /* default: monospace */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you use Firebug 1.11+, you can do it:

1) Open the `firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi` or your .xpi file (extract) with Winrar/Winzip archive program

2) Search the line font-family: monospace; in all .css files

3) Replace all `font-family: monospace;` => `font-family: consolas, monospace !important;`

4) Save the file, do it archive (zip, rar) and later change it's extension => `.xpi`

5) Restart the Firefox.